# Calculating Rotational Temperature from an FTIR Spectrum

Tags: physical-chemistry, spectroscopy, ir-spectroscopy, gas-phase-chemistry

I am trying to calculate the rotational temperature of a sample of gas phase HCN from an FTIR spectrum. It's a 10 Torr sample in a 10 cm gas cell, held at room temperature. In theory, I should be able to make a semi-log plot of the rotational peak intensities vs. the energy of the transition and pull the rotational temperature from the slope according to the Boltzmann distribution using the following general equation:
$$ ln(\frac{A_{J}}{g_{J}}) = -\frac{\varepsilon_{J}}{k_{B}T} $$
Where $A_{J}$ is the peak intensity for a given transition, $\varepsilon_{J}$ is the energy of the transition, and $g_{J}$ is its degeneracy.

However, whenever I try to make this calculation, regardless of the the units I use for energy or whether I'm taking into consideration more complex factors, like Honl-London, I get a nonsensical rotational temperature, usually on the order of 5-20 Kelvin. Does anyone know where I might be going wrong?

Additionally, I'm including pastebin links with the portion of raw FTIR data I am working with, and the peak assignments, with heights, energies, J states, degeneracies, and FWHM

[FTIR Data](https://pastebin.com/Gdk6Fnia)

[Peak Assignments](https://pastebin.com/Z5QjxSNK)

Comment: [This is from a paper on HCN in planet-forming disks](https://zenodo.org/record/3758051) - and I know nothing about astro*, so this might be far off base - but the rotational temps for $\ce{HCN}$ range from 11 to 21 K (+/- some). I believe you need the high-temperature limit even at room temperature but could be wrong. TLDR: I don't think you're that far off.

Comment: The relative population for a (rigid rotor)diatomic is given by the weighted Boltzmann distribution $\displaystyle (2J+1)\exp(-Bhc(J(J+1)/(k_BT))$ where $B$ is in cm$^{-1}$ and $c$ the speed of light in cm/s and $k_B$ the Boltzmann const. This should give an approx temperature but for an accurate value you will need transition probabilities (Honh-London) and also the fact that it is the population difference between levels that matters but for rotational levels in v=0 to v=1 this may be a small effect.

Comment: @porphyrin Using your equation gives a much better result of 317 K, although it's still off by ~20 K. I have two different literature methods for calculating Honl-London factors but that results in rotational temperatures greater than 400 K, which makes me think I'm using them incorrectly. How would I incorporate them in?

Comment: The fit to the equation I showed needs two parameters, (temperature and amplitude) to get a good fit by non-linear least squares. However,  you probably  need to account for centrifugal distortion and possibly vib-rot coupling and so use a different energy function. You will find the equations in most phys. chem. and spectroscopy textbooks. Try this before any more fancy stuff.